# Increasing the sample size for ttest without additional observations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation, sample-size

I am currently handling some satistical data but my sample size is too small fot testing and my suppervisor suggested me the following idea:

Consider 2 samples *x, y* and we want to compare the difference of means *mean(x)-mean(y)*. Instead of using a 2 sampled ttest (or something else) consider the following transformation:

**Let z be all possible 2 paired difference of the elements of x minus the elements of y**

Next I would test if the mean of *z* is different to 0. 
Obviously this is not equivalent since I even increase the sample size (if x and y have n elements each then z has n^2 elements)

What is the catch?  I never heard anything about such a transformation, is this established?

Comment: By the same argument you could repeat your small samples as many times as you'd like. I don't think this would solve the problem though. You fix "too small sample" problem by getting more data.

Comment: What do you mean `too small for testing`? You did not find a significant result? If you want to compare the mean of x and y use a two sample t test.

Comment: my x and y are sometime of length 2 each, this will allways produce H0 obviously. But with this transformation i have n=4 and this can get significant. E.g. 100,100 is larger than 0,0 wich will be found by this transformation+1sample test. (Fixing by getting more data is not possible)

Comment: Then you need more than 2 data points. Artificially "augmenting" your data to show you what you want to see is just wrong.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I think the problem (intuitively) is that the observations of z will no longer be IID now, which is a critical assumption for t-test. But we should try to prove this. Maybe your supervisor is right. Interesting problem nevertheless.

Comment: Btw, you should change the title to something more relevant such as "Increasing the size of sample for t-test without additional observations".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from my comment above:

Let $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ for $i=1,2,...N$ be two set of i.i.d random variables, s.t. $X_i \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2)$ and $Y_i \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2), \forall i$, and $\sigma \neq 0$.

Let $Z_{ij}:=X_i - Y_j$

So we have $N^2$ random variables.

Now, let $Z_{ij}$ be mutually independent. Then from independence:

$E[Z_{ij}Z_{ik}] = E[Z_{ij}]E[Z_{ik}]$

$LHS= E[(X_i-Y_j)(X_i-Y_k)]$

$=E[X_i^2] + E[Y_i]E[Y_k] - E[X_i]E[Y_j]- E[X_i]E[Y_k]$

$RHS=(E[X_i]-E[Y_j])(E[X_i]-E[Y_k])$

$=E^2[X_i] + E[Y_i]E[Y_k] - E[X_i]E[Y_j]- E[X_i]E[Y_k]$

Putting, $LHS=RHS$:

$E[X_i^2] - E^2[X_i] \equiv \sigma^2 =0$

This is clearly a contradiction. Hence, $Z_{ij}$ are not independent and therefore t-test cannot be used to test whether the mean of $Z_{ij}$ is zero.

Comment: Very nice argumentation. Makes sense that you cannot get more information without obtaining more data.